# requests / aiohttp with SOCKS5. 0x05: Connection refused

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp, socks, pysocks

I have two versions of the program:

- Synchronous, using `requests` library;
- Asynchronous, using `aiohttp` library.

It is necessary to make requests to a site using SOCKS5 proxy. After installing the necessary libraries to work with SOCKS5 proxies, I tried making requests to a few sites. Everything worked fine with all sites except the necessary one. When sending a request to it, an error appeared:

> 0x05: Connection refused

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site. There is no need to mark a question as `[solved]`, or to comment in the question itself that an answer follows. Just post the answer, and in this case since you are [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), make sure to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) after the 2-day wait on self-answers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the `requests` library in a couple minutes. But I didn't find a solution for `aiohttp`, so it took me several hours to find a solution on my own.

I finally found a solution, so I'm going to publish solutions for each of the libraries below to help other developers save time in solving the same problem.

---

To make a successful request to such a site try to enable reverse DNS (rDNS). I will describe how to do it for `requests` and `aiohttp` libraries.

## requests

To enable rDNS, you need to use `socks5h://...` instead of `socks5://...` in a proxy URL.

**requirements.txt**

```
PySocks==1.7.1
requests==2.31.0
```

**main.py**

```py
import requests


def main():
    proxy = 'socks5://username:password@0.0.0.0:1111'
    proxy = proxy.replace('socks5://', 'socks5h://')
    
    # or just 
    # proxy = 'socks5h://username:password@0.0.0.0:1111'

    response = requests.get(url='https://www.example.com/', proxies={'http': proxy, 'https': proxy})
    print(response.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## aiohttp

To enable rDNS, you need to pass the `rdns=True` parameter during initialization of the `ProxyConnector`.

**requirements.txt**

```
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiohttp-socks==0.8.0
PySocks==1.7.1
```

**main.py**

```py
import asyncio

import aiohttp
from aiohttp_socks import ProxyConnector


async def main():
    proxy = 'socks5://username:password@0.0.0.0:1111'
    connector = ProxyConnector.from_url(url=proxy, rdns=True)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
        async with session.get(url='https://www.example.com/') as response:
            print(await response.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```